# Vary Row numbers in SAS Loop

Tags: loops, sas, row, offset

I have a NXN dataset from which i would like to have a one row (1XN) output. I need to calculate percentages in each column. As I move along the column the Numerator and Denominator keep on reducing from 1 row below.

Data I Have:

```
Category Month 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Categ_1 Month_1 15 15 15 14 14 13 13 13 13 13
Categ_1 Month_2 8 8 8 7 6 5 5 5 5 5
Categ_1 Month_3 15 15 14 14 14 12 11 11 11 10
Categ_1 Month_4 17 17 17 15 14 14 13 12 11 11
Categ_1 Month_5 25 25 25 23 21 19 18 16 16 16
Categ_1 Month_6 21 21 18 17 14 13 12 11 11 8
Categ_1 Month_7 29 28 25 23 20 18 15 14 13 13
Categ_1 Month_8 32 31 30 28 25 23 21 20 18 17
Categ_1 Month_9 38 37 35 32 27 24 23 20 17 16
Categ_1 Month_10 30 30 28 27 24 21 20 18 17 17
```

What I want is

```
Categ_1 100% 99% 94% 87% 82% 79% 76% 76% 78% 87%
```

where for column 1 (i.e. 100%) = (total in 0th month)/(total in 0th month)
where for column 2 (i.e. 99%) = (total in 1th month-last row)/(total in 0th month-last row) and so on...

I have done it in excel using a simple OFFSET formula. It would be great if anyone can help me code it in SAS. I am finding it difficult to loop accross column while varying the rows to consider vary as well.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by last row/ one row below. (total in 1th month-total in 2th month)?

Comment: in column 2 (99%) what i want is = sum of first 9 rows of column 2 / sum of first 9 rows of column 1

Comment: So you want a sum of the upper diagonal of a matrix (Represented as a SAS dataset)? Do you have SAS/IML licensed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives the correct output. The trick is to loop over all variables and with every step (iteration of the datastep) leave one more out.

```
DATA in_data ; 
   INPUT Category $ Month $ var_0 - var_9 ; 
   DATALINES; 
Categ_1 Month_1 15 15 15 14 14 13 13 13 13 13
Categ_1 Month_2 8 8 8 7 6 5 5 5 5 5
Categ_1 Month_3 15 15 14 14 14 12 11 11 11 10
Categ_1 Month_4 17 17 17 15 14 14 13 12 11 11
Categ_1 Month_5 25 25 25 23 21 19 18 16 16 16
Categ_1 Month_6 21 21 18 17 14 13 12 11 11 8
Categ_1 Month_7 29 28 25 23 20 18 15 14 13 13
Categ_1 Month_8 32 31 30 28 25 23 21 20 18 17
Categ_1 Month_9 38 37 35 32 27 24 23 20 17 16
Categ_1 Month_10 30 30 28 27 24 21 20 18 17 17

; 

data out_data;
do until (last.Category);
    set in_data;
    format out_0 - out_9 percent.;
    array in  [*] var_0 - var_9;
    array out [*] out_0 - out_9;
    by Category;
    if first.Category then count = 0;
    count + 1;
    do i = 1 to dim(in) + 1 - count;
        out[i] = sum(out[i],in[i]);
        if dim(in) + 1 - i = count then out[i] = out[i] /out[1];
    end; 
end;
    drop var_: month i count;
run;
```

edit: build an error in while editing, fixed now

Comment: What was the error? There should be no need to tweak the code for multiple categories, only for additional Variables. have you sorted your data by `Category` and `Month`?

Comment: It is calculating for the first category only and rest are coming as .

Comment: Awesome!! I was also trying with first. but somehow it was not working. My Bad! GREAT! :)